# PIG- timeout inside a udf

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I would like to introduce a timeout in my udf function. As fas as I understand the annotation

> MonitoredUDF

will terminate the exec function and return null. However, since there may be some successful previous processing I want it to avoid throwing away all that data. Ideally I would like to implement a timeout for a specific portion of the code inside the UDF. Any idea of how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at ErrorHandler and TimeoutHadler of MonitorUdf ?

Here from http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/udf.html

> If desired, custom logic can also be implemented for error handling by
>   creating a subclass of MonitoredUDFExecutor.ErrorCallback, and
>   overriding its handleError and/or handleTimeout methods. Both of those
>   methods are static, and are passed in the instance of the EvalFunc
>   that produced an exception, as well as an exception, so you may use
>   any state you have in the UDF to process the errors as desired. The
>   default behavior is to increment Hadoop counters every time an error
>   is encountered. Once you have an implementation of the ErrorCallback
>   that performs your custom logic, you can provide it in the annotation:

```
import org.apache.pig.builtin.MonitoredUDF;

@MonitoredUDF(errorCallback=MySpecialErrorCallback.class)
public class MyUDF extends EvalFunc<Integer> {
  /* implementation goes here */
}
```